# SQLAlchemy Expression Language - INSERT SELECT with literal values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've just started using the SQLAlchemy SQL Expression Language, and I'm trying to insert into a table values from an existing tables and literal values. I'm trying to emulate this SQL statement in the SQL Expression language:

```
INSERT INTO b_Customers 
(CustomerID, 
CustomerName, 
CustomerType,
IsCurrent,
FirstObserved,
LastObserved)

SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerType, 1, '2018-01-23', '2018-01-23'
FROM s_Customers
```

Here's some setup Python code I'm running:

```
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO
import csv

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, Date, String, MetaData, ForeignKey, bindparam, text
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal_column, literal

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

metadata = MetaData()
stage = Table('s_Customers', metadata,
    Column('CustomerID', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('CustomerName', String),
    Column('CustomerType', String),
)

base = Table('b_Customers', metadata,
    Column('CustomerID', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('CustomerName', String),
    Column('CustomerType', String),
    Column('IsCurrent', Integer),
    Column('FirstObserved', Date),
    Column('LastObserved', Date),
)

metadata.create_all(engine)

insert_data = u'''CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerType
1,Jannet,Preferred
2,Daniel,Regular
3,Casper,Regular'''

table_to_insert = StringIO(insert_data)
table_values = list(csv.DictReader(table_to_insert))

conn = engine.connect()
stmt = stage.insert().values(table_values)
conn.execute(stmt)
```

And here's where I'm stuck:

```
stmt = base.insert().from_select(list(stage.columns) + [bindparam(1, 'IsCurrent'), 
                                                        bindparam(datetime(2018, 1, 23), 'FirstObserved'), 
                                                        bindparam(datetime(2018, 1, 23), 'LastObserved')],
                                stage)
conn.execute(stmt)
```

Here's the stack trace from running the above code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a3d52b22c83e> in <module>()
      3                                                         bindparam(datetime(2018, 1, 23), 'LastObserved')],
      4                                 stage)
----> 5 conn.execute(stmt)

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.pyc in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    946             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object)
    947         else:
--> 948             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    949 
    950     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.pyc in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    267     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
    268         if self.supports_execution:
--> 269             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    270         else:
    271             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.pyc in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1051                 inline=len(distilled_params) > 1,
   1052                 schema_translate_map=self.schema_for_object
-> 1053                 if not self.schema_for_object.is_default else None)
   1054 
   1055         ret = self._execute_context(

<string> in <lambda>(self, bind, dialect, **kw)

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.pyc in compile(self, default, bind, dialect, **kw)
    440             else:
    441                 dialect = default.StrCompileDialect()
--> 442         return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
    443 
    444     def _compiler(self, dialect, **kw):

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.pyc in _compiler(self, dialect, **kw)
    446         Dialect."""
    447 
--> 448         return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
    449 
    450     def __str__(self):

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.pyc in __init__(self, dialect, statement, column_keys, inline, **kwargs)
    451         # dialect.label_length or dialect.max_identifier_length
    452         self.truncated_names = {}
--> 453         Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
    454 
    455         if (

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.pyc in __init__(self, dialect, statement, bind, schema_translate_map, compile_kwargs)
    217             if self.can_execute:
    218                 self.execution_options = statement._execution_options
--> 219             self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
    220 
    221     @util.deprecated("0.7", ":class:`.Compiled` objects now compile "

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.pyc in process(self, obj, **kwargs)
    243 
    244     def process(self, obj, **kwargs):
--> 245         return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
    246 
    247     def __str__(self):

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.pyc in _compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw)
     79                     raise exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(visitor, cls)
     80                 else:
---> 81                     return meth(self, **kw)
     82         else:
     83             # The optimization opportunity is lost for this case because the

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.pyc in visit_insert(self, insert_stmt, asfrom, **kw)
   2032 
   2033         crud_params = crud._setup_crud_params(
-> 2034             self, insert_stmt, crud.ISINSERT, **kw)
   2035 
   2036         if not crud_params and \

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.pyc in _setup_crud_params(compiler, stmt, local_stmt_type, **kw)
     55     try:
     56         if local_stmt_type in (ISINSERT, ISUPDATE):
---> 57             return _get_crud_params(compiler, stmt, **kw)
     58     finally:
     59         if should_restore:

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.pyc in _get_crud_params(compiler, stmt, **kw)
    130             compiler, stmt, parameters,
    131             _getattr_col_key, _column_as_key,
--> 132             _col_bind_name, check_columns, values, kw)
    133     else:
    134         _scan_cols(

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.pyc in _scan_insert_from_select_cols(compiler, stmt, parameters, _getattr_col_key, _column_as_key, _col_bind_name, check_columns, values, kw)
    211 
    212     cols = [stmt.table.c[_column_as_key(name)]
--> 213             for name in stmt.select_names]
    214 
    215     compiler._insert_from_select = stmt.select

C:\Users\rdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    192 
    193     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 194         return self._data[key]
    195 
    196     def __delitem__(self, key):

KeyError: 1
```

I've also tried using literal() and literal_column() and those haven't been successful.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, what's the problem? Any error message to post?

Comment: Hi Luis, I should've posted the stack trace. I will edit my post and add it in.

Comment: I added the stack trace in there. I'm trying to insert literal/constant values alongside the columns from the stage table, but I'm instead getting this KeyError.

Comment: Seems to me that you are mixing column names with data on method  from_select(names, select, include_defaults=True). First arguments is column names, so list(base.columns) looks ok to me. Second argument is the select and there is where you should try to build the result with stage columns plus your literal values.  Check from_select docs here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html

Answer (score 3):

I've got it. I have to create another selectable with those literal columns added in, and then select from that:

```
stage_w_columns = select(list(stage.columns) + [literal(1).label('IsCurrent'),
                                           literal(datetime(2018, 1, 23)).label('FirstObserved'),
                                           literal(datetime(2018, 1, 23)).label('LastObserved')])
stmt = base.insert().from_select(stage_w_columns.columns, stage_w_columns)
conn.execute(stmt)
```

Thanks Luis for pointing me in the right direction!