# SQLAlchemy filter query for Hybrid Property Enum

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have these models in my FastApi Python project with SqlAlchemy:

```
class Status(Enum):
    SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"
    FAILURE = "FAILURE"

class BarModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Bar"

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)


class FooModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    flag_one = Column(Boolean, nullable=True, default=None)

    bar = relationship("BarModel", lazy="joined", uselist=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def hybrid_enum(self) -> Status:
       if (
           self.flag_one
           and self.bar is not None
           and self.bar.name is not None
       ):
           return Status.SUCCESS
       else:
           return Status.FAILURE
```

My hybrid_enum property works like a charm when reading data from the database.
However, when i want to do a filter query based on the hybrid property:

```
         db.query(FooModel)
         .filter(FooModel.hybrid_enum == Status.SUCCESS)
         .all(),
```

I receive the following error:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor
> 'Comparator' object associated with FooModel.bar has an
> attribute 'name'

I also tried to join the BarModel, but it results in the same error. What am i missing here?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I suppose you need to implement the @hybrid_enum.expression part (See how there's a "radius" property and a "radius.expression" in the docs https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior ). Your property works when you have Python _instances_ . When you want to use them in the SQL "world" (meaning: in queries) you need to generate a query-looking return value (SQL-friendly, if you may?).

Comment: Good point, i've read about this, but i'm having a hard time converting this "if-and-not-then return Enum" stuff to an SQL expression. Any advice?

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to answer this, and PLEASE, do more research before using what I'm about to say, but if you can use CASE and EXISTS, _maaaybe_ the following SQLFiddle might give you a hint? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/530e6/7 . Also, you don't have to use raw SQL in your .expression method. You can (and probably should) leverage SqlAlchemy for that. I.E.: where the fiddle says `Foo.flag_one`, you can use `cls.flag_one` (the .expression method is a classmethod). You can have your .expression method return a SqlAlchemy CASE object (an instance of `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case` )

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, i've created a case statement in the expression, but i still have trouble with the join. I still get the same error message. Should i somehow do the join in the case statement instead of the actual query?

Comment: so... because both primary keys are shared by both models (the PK of Foo is a FK in Bar) you _shouldn't_ need a join. You could leverage the fact that rows in table "Bar" will have the same key as its "foo" counterpart. You still would need to build the SELECT(1) statement. To select 1 (or `true`) you can take a look to SqlAlchemy's literal ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/48413521/289011 )